# Custom Places to show in google places ios sdk

Tags: swift4, google-places-api

How can i show custom lis of places / addresses from a json file to show in google places autocomplete search instead of getting them from google places api?

Comment: so are you trying to achieve the behavior of the autocomplete search that google provides ? 
2- what is this addresses from a json file ? how are you accessing that and why ?

Comment: Yes i would like to achieve GMSplacesAutocomple search with custom data. Since google maps does not have my local 12,000 addresses i can provide address search feature through my own data?